# Monodroid - Excel Files

Tags: android, excel, mono

I'd like to create small Excel worksheet from an android application using Mono for Android.
I tried using both EPPlus and ExcelLibrary .NET libraries, however I'm having trouble building the project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

Is there any fix for that or other way to manipulate Excel files through Mono for Android ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reference a pre-built .NET 4.0 assembly into your Mono for Android project. You can't reliably do this (sometimes it works if you get lucky). MonoTouch and Mono for Android do not have a System.Drawing assembly, so you can't use libraries that link to it.

What you'll need to do is create a new project for the EPPlus or ExcelLibrary libraries and use the Mono for Android Library Project type. You'll probably also need to make some modifications to the project such that it doesn't use the parts of System.Drawing that Mono for Android don't have (it has a few bits and pieces like System.Drawing.RectangleF and SizeF, but is missing most of it).

I was going to work on doing this for MonoTouch using the [npoi](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) project (which has a more agreeable license than EPPlus), but have been too busy with other things.

I've got a fork of npoi that I'm working on cleaning up the API here: https://github.com/jstedfast/npoi/tree/enumification

Once I finish that and get that merged upstream, my plan is to create a new branch where I will be working on porting the library to the subset of .NET that MonoTouch and Mono4Android use. I'll probably call it "mobile" or something.

In the meantime, the quick and dirt fix is to just create a new Mono for Android Library project, add all the source files to it in the same way that npoi has, and then try building. It will fail, but the errors will give you a good starting point for figuring out which parts of the library to rip out mercilessly. Keep doing that until it compiles.

If you use either of the npoi repositories that I linked to above, I've already done some of the work to make font.metrics and some other resource file I can't think of build properly for MonoTouch/Android, so there will be a little less work to do than if you use a release like 1.2.5.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply I had no idea some people were working on a fork like this.
I'll keep an eye on it, for now I used the ExcelWriter class from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33850/Generate-Excel-files-without-using-Microsoft-Excel
And it worked like a charm for me :p

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out, too... maybe it'll save me a lot of work :-)

Comment: @jstedfast: What is the current state of your npoi branch? is it usable for xamarin`s monotouch/monodroid?

Comment: I think my enum branch got merged into upstream NPOI, but I haven't worked on it since so it still likely uses bits that aren't available in MonoTouch and MonoDroid